# Gatling - UniformRandomSwitch doesn't work as expected

Tags: scala, csv, gatling

I want to iterate through all items of a csv file and for each item I want to distribute uniform the request so that all SearchProduct (SearchProduct1, SearchProduct2 and SearchProduct3) functions are called the same times.

```
    val products= csv("products.csv").records

    val start= exec(repeat(products.size, "n"){
        feed(products.queue)
        .uniformRandomSwitch(
            exec(searchProduct1), 
            exec(searchProduct2), 
            exec(searchProduct3)
        )
    })
```

I expect that If I have 9 products, the function SearchProduct1 is called 3 times, the function SearchProduct2 is called 3 times and the function SearchProduct3 also is called 3 times.

But the statistics show me many times that the function SearchProduct3 was called 5 times and the SearchProduct2 and SearchProduct1 were called 2 times. Am I doing anithing wrong? Should I do the repeat inside the `uniformRandomSwitch`?

So I understand the `uniformRandomSwitch` that the probability of executing one of these three functions is the same. It could be possible that in 9 iterations, 8 times is executed the SearchProduct1 and 1 time SearchProduct2 (and the SearchProduct3 never). But with `uniformRandomSwitch` I am not forcing to execute the same times every function. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the `roundRobinSwitch` directive. This will iterate through each chain, moving on to the next and then repeating at the beginning, as new requests come through.

With `uniformRandomSwitch` each chain has a `1/N` chance of being called. Only over many iterations would the number of calls converge, given your example, to 3/3/3.

Comment: Totally agree with you!